# Scope and Order AJAX Callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

This code needs to 1) check if users are online 2) get their information from a slightly different URL and 3) output both to HTML. It works, but inconsistently. In some cases when running the function for outputting the HTML it says that the data from the first request (online or not) is undefined. Right now streamData and userData are globals. But I wish I could get it to work without that. Having issues getting both data sources to consistently be available in the same place at the same time.

```
  var getOnline = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < twitchFaves.length; i++) {
      userName = twitchFaves[i];
      streamAjaxOnline(userName);
    }
  }
  var streamAjaxOnline = function(userName){
    $.ajax({
      type        : 'GET',
      url         :  "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/" + userName,
      dataType    : 'jsonp',
      success     : function(twitchData) {

        streamData = twitchData;
        if (streamData.stream){
          userAjaxOnline(userName);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  var userAjaxOnline = function(userName){
    $.ajax({
      type        : 'GET',
      url         :  "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/" + userName,
      dataType    : 'jsonp',
      success     : function(twitchData) {
        userData = twitchData;
        displayTwitchOnline(streamData, userData);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: that code... can't work. the multiple iterations are going to walk all over each other due to the globals and asynchronous logic. The for loop isn't going to wait on the asynchronous logic to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now streamData and userData are globals

That's really bad. It means that multiple calls to the functions will share the same variables and overwrite the results of each other.

> But I wish I could get it to work without that.

That's relatively easy: Pass the data to the functions instead. A very simple solution would be:

```
var streamAjaxOnline = function(userName) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/" + userName,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(twitchData) {
      if (streamData.stream) {
        userAjaxOnline(userName, streamData); // pass streamData here
      }
    }
  });
}
var userAjaxOnline = function(userName, streamData) { // accept streamData here
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/" + userName,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(twitchData) {
      // no need to store userData if you only use it here
      displayTwitchOnline(streamData, twitchData);
    }
  });
}
```